# How to include a client certificate for the client application in an Android and MAUI application?

Tags: maui

I have a gRPC service and the client. I would like to force the client include a client certificate, to avoid that others application could call to the service.

The client is an Android application created with MAUI, and it will be distribute locally sharing the APK file, I will not publish it in the App Store.

The way that I was thinking to do is to add a client certificate as embedded resource of the project, I guess that this include the certificate inside the APK, but I have doubts if this is secure.

One doubt is if some that could get the APK could extract the certificate from the APK and use it.

I don't know what Android does with the embedded resoureces. Are they extracted and copied in the storage? If this is true, what storage? Because there are two storages, SecureStorage and normal storage. In which storage would be copied?

Or perhaps it is not extracted from embedded resources, because in code, the way to access to the embedded  resources is in this way:

```
var myAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
using var miStream = myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyProjectName.appsettings.json");
```

In this case I am acceding to the appsettings file, but I didn't copy it to storage neither I am acceding to the storage.

In sumary, I would like to know how safe it is to include a certificate in the APK and which it would be the best way to distribute a client certificate.

Thanks.

Comment: I’m not a security expert, but you could store an encrypted form of the certificate, and decrypt it in memory only. So it never exists in storage in an unencrypted form.

Comment: Yes, I would think in this option, but I think the client needs to know the key to decrypt, so I have to include in code or in some way with the application, so I think it doesn't offer more security.

Comment: Challenge-response. Use a technique that associates a generated key with a given user name. User signs up / logs in. A GUID value is generated on server, and stored on server with that username. Securely send GUID to app, which runs some code based on that GUID, to combine it with local data compiled into app. App sends result back to server, which has run same code once, and stored the expected result with the username. Harder to reverse-engiineer. And any single response is only valid for a given username.

Comment: It is a good aproach. But i am thinking that all the process depends on the username and password. So if someone could get this credentials, could get the GUID generated by the server. So perhaps it doesn't increase the secuery but increase complexity. The idea of the certificate is it it is that it adds a second way to authenticate. one is user name an password, someone that the users knows, and the certificate it is a scond layer of security, something that the user has. So if someone stoles the credentials, still needs to stole the certificate.

Comment: This is essentially how an Authentication server works. The user's name, password, etc are encrypted with the server's unique key (i.e., a long alphanumeric number). Your data server decrypts that data with the same key. So only the authentication server and the data server know that unique encryption. It is much more secure because the "certificate" is not stored with the APK.

Comment: *"If someone could get this credentials, could get the GUID generated by the server."* (1) They would still have to reverse-engineer the algorithm that is run inside the app. That's why I've entangled the GUID with an algorithm. (2) Perhaps you want "two-factor authentication". Authenticate user. (3) Bottom line: By Definition, if you are trying to protect against a highly sophisticated attacker, who is able to completely reverse-engineer your app, then there is nothing you can do in the app itself that is "secure". I am suggesting a more realistic goal, of making reverse-engineering "harder".

Comment: Yes, perhaps when part of the security is outside the server, you lose the control how to handle, although you can try to make it harder. But at the end, if someone is good enough, can access it anyway.